# ¿Cómo evitar que un cron job me envíe un email cada vez que se ejecuta?

Tags: ssh, cron

Tengo configurado un cron job que se ejecuta cada dos horas:

```
0   */2 *   *   *   /bin/sh /ruta/mi-script.sh
```

Pero quisiera evitar que me envíe un e-mail cada vez que se ejecuta.

Estoy trabajando desde BlueHost, y tiene configurado que el email se envíe siempre. No quiero llenar mi bandeja de entrada con esos mensajes.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías probar algunas formas, el éxito dependerá de lo que te permita el proveedor, veamos:

#### 1. Redirigir la salida

```
0   */2 *   *   *   /bin/sh /ruta/mi-script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Esto lo que hace es redirigir la salida estándar y la salida de error al clásico  colector de basura de unix `/dev/null`. Podrías eventualmente dejar la salida de error para que pase por el mail y desactivar solo la estándar:

```
0   */2 *   *   *   /bin/sh /ruta/mi-script.sh >/dev/null
```

#### 2. Quitar el MAILTO

Si tienes acceso a editar el archivo `/etc/crontab` puedes editar la variable `MAILTO` dejándola en blanco `MAILTO=""`

#### 3. Configurar el demonio del cron para que la salida vaya a un log

Si puedes editar `/etc/sysconfig/crond`, podrías agregar el parámetro `-s` para redirigir la salida al log del sistema y `-m off` para deshabilitar el envío de mails

Ten en cuenta que las opciones 2 y 3 requieren reiniciar el demonio del cron.

Referencia: https://www.putorius.net/2015/03/stop-cron-daemon-from-sending-email-for.html

Comment: Gracias. Lo puse como indicas en la opción 1 y parece que está funcionando...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes evitar ser notificado de varias formas, una de ellas es lanzar cada comando con una redirección a null, por ejemplo, si tu comando es php cron.php, entonces:

```
php cron.php>/dev/null 2>&1
```

De esta forma cron no genera notificación al no haber salida alguna. Otra forma sería desabilitar las notificaciones desde la propia configuración de cron, edita cron:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Busca la línea MAILTO y cámbiala a vacío o créala arriba del todo si no existe:

```
MAILTO=""
```

Pero esto dependerá de la versión del sistema gnu/linux usado.

Comment: Gracias. No me interesa deshabilitarlo del todo, pues me interesa para otros cron semanales o mensuales...  ¿el comando `/dev/null 2>&1` no puede ir en el script `.sh`?  ¿dónde tendría que ponerlo?

Comment: Así es, el comando de redirección lo puedes poner detrás de cada comando, sea un script php, bash, perl, un binario o cualquier otro.

Comment: Puse  `/dev/null 2>&1` en mi script y me manda un email que dice: `Permission denied`

Comment: Parece que no tienes permisos para acceder a /dev/null con el usuario que lanza cron. ¿Qué permisos tiene /dev/null? ¿puedes hacer un ls -l /dev/null?

Comment: Arroja esto: `crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Feb 23 06:27 /dev/null`  Estoy en un hosting compartido de BlueHost.

Comment: Pero en otro comentario dices que ya te funciona, no?

Comment: Vale, espera, releyendo... ¿puede que hayas puesto la regla "dentro" del script?

Comment: Me funciona como indicó @PatricioMoracho, poniéndolo en la llamada del cron. Yo intentaba ponerlo dentro del script `.sh` y era ahí que me daba `Permission denied`

Comment: Perdón, tal vez me expliqué mal en mi anterior comentario, efectivamente va en la línea del cron, no en el script, aunque debería funcionar si quieres hacerlo de forma individual por los comandos del propio script, pero entonces necesitaríamos el código fuente, porque la sintaxis puede variar un poco...